# Unable to access data from pulled NVMe PCIe drives using SIIG adapter

Tags: nvme, enclosures, external

I purchased a SIIG JU-SA0W11-S1 USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C to M.2 PCIe NVMe SSD enclosure to recover data from failed laptops after pulling the NVMe drive. The enclosure is compatible with PCIe 3.1a and back and supports PCIe NVMe SSD up to 2TB in 2230, 2242, 2260 and 2280 form factor.

Regardless of what NVMe drive I pull and plug into this adapter, I am told that the drive is unreadable and needs to be formatted when plugged into a Mac (with full NTFS support) or it appears in Windows 10 Disk Management as a (weirdly-sized) Healthy (GPT Protected Partition). Diskpart shows the drive as the correct size with no space available.

This occurs with ALL NVMe drives that I have tried to access. I am currently trying with a WD Black 500GB SN750 (WDS500G3X0C) and SK hynix 256GB (HFS256GDE9X081N). After cleaning and reformatting a WD 256GB SN730, it works fine but that defeats the purpose of trying to access the data from dead computers' drives.

I'm not sure what is in play. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You say that you needed to reformat the SSD in order to use it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I have failed laptop(s). I have pulled the NVMe PCIe cards to recover data or to move to a new computer. Using the above-mentioned enclosure, the drive shows the messages indicated above. What's wrong with reformatting is that makes it really difficult to copy data from the pulled NVMe PCIe, which is the stated purpose at the beginning of the question. Thanks for reading and assisting!

Comment: Have you tried an alternate adapter? It seems that if every drive fails in this one your best first course would be to get a different one, preferably a different model/controller/brand.